# checklogin php logging system

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I am trying to make a simple login system and I am very new to PHP and creating such a thing. I have no idea why my code does not redirect to the site I need it to go to. I think I need a fresh set of eyes or ideas as to why it is met with "SERVER ERROR." I have tried so many different ones but none work or my understanding of what to change is faulty. I have spent days trying to figure out why none of these work for me.

Few questions - please keep in mind I am very new to this:

1. If I am accessing a database to pull the username and password from a server that the php file is on, I can leave the "localhost" correct?
2. If I do not get a "SERVER ERROR" but just a blank white screen, does that mean I connected to the server correctly and just no information is being 
   displayed?
3. I have tried a dozen different `checklogin` files, none of them work and I do not know why, is this on my end?

My login.php page

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="POST"> 
   <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"     required="required" /> <br/>
       <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"     placeholder="Password" required="required" /> <br/><br>

       <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
       <input type="button" onclick="location.href='SeniorDB_Main.php';"     value="Return to Register" />
    </form>
```

checklogin #1 - Received with SERVER ERROR

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $bool = true;

    mysql_connect("localhost", "[username]", "[password]") or die (mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("[database_name]") or die ("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database

    $query = mysql_query("Select * from users WHERE username='$username'"); // Query the users table
    $exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if username exists
    $table_users = "test":
    $table_password = "test";

    if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing username
    {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) // display all rows from query
       {
          $table_users = $row['username']; // the first username row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
          $table_password = $row['password']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_password, and so on until the query is finished
       }
       if(($username == $table_users) && ($password == $table_password))// checks if there are any matching fields
       {
          if($password == $table_password)
          {
             $_SESSION['user'] = $username; //set the username in a session. This serves as a global variable
             header("location: SeniorDB_DBLibrary.php"); // redirects the user to the authenticated home page
          }
       }
?>
```

Checklogin #2 - Received with Blank White Page

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password'])
     {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('You did not complete all of the required fields')
            window.location.href='htmlogin.html'
            </SCRIPT>");
    exit();
         }


    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
            window.location.href='SeniorDB_DBLibrary'
            </SCRIPT>");
    exit();
    }
    else{
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
            window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
            </SCRIPT>");
    exit();
       }
    }
    else{
    }
    ?>
```

checklogin #3 - Logs in, but calls upon the user input instead of from the database - is it possible to call the database entries to match it with this one?

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "[username]", "[password]") or die (mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("[database_name]") or die ("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database

    if (empty($_SESSION['users'])) {

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

        if ($username == $_POST['username'] && $password == $_POST['password']) {

            // redirect to index.php to welcome the logged in user:
            header('Location: SeniorDB_DBLibrary.php');
            exit;
        }
        else {
            die("ERROR: Incorrect username or password!");
        }

    }
?>
```

[image]

---

### Thank you Rasclatt - you helped solve everything. If anyone is here to see how this was worked out, check out his answer

Comment: What version of PHP error are you running? Is there anything in your PHP error log?

Comment: If you're still learning, it's best to do it the right way from the start. `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for over 2 years now. It's strongly advised to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @chris85 I am using PHP 5.4 I believe. It's my University server. I am unsure how to check PHP error log

Comment: @icecub Is what I am using not MySQLi or PDO? I was not taught a difference in these functions at my University.

Comment: It's mostly about security. MySQL is wide open to SQL injection. Basicly it allows anyone to do things with your database that you really don't want them to. Tell your University to start teaching you updated and proper coding instead of this mess. - If you're really interested in learning (and not just a quick fix), feel free to click my profile here and contact me through email. We could setup a teamviewer session so I can teach you a thing or two :)

Comment: @mudwomp have you gotten any further with this?

Comment: @icecub as of right now Icecub, I am honestly looking for a quick fix since my presentation is in 6 days and this is the last part I need. I would love to learn about it some other time when I don't have this looming Senior Design coming up. Do you have any ideas as to why my `checklogin` files are not working correctly? I need a fresh set of eyes, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Rasclatt unfortunately I have not. I have been trying to get this to work for days, it's the last part of my senior project and I feel I "have" it but it's not working. So you could say I'm at my wit's end right now. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are these just 3 different attempts? Is that why they are all named as `checklogin`?

Comment: I presume so. I am guessing you are using plaintext passwords?

Comment: Checklogin attempt 1 has two syntax errors: `$table_users = "test":` should be `$table_users = "test";` (semicolon at the end) 2) Needs another brace (`}`) at the very end of the snippit

Comment: @Rasclatt those are all 3 different attempts yes. I just copy / pasted into the `checklogin.php` on the server when I tried these ones. They are just plaintext passwords, no encryption or anything

Comment: @Rasclatt  I tested the 2nd one (#2) and changed the `:` to `;` and added the closing `}`. Now it communicates with the server, but it is met with a blank page, instead of going straight to the main page `SeniorDB_DBLibrary.php`. This is the site that I made for my project http://polonium.forest.usf.edu/~sngamwon/SeniorProject/SeniorDB_Main.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need a better teacher if this is what you are being taught. You need to use a secure way of database connection and you need to use functions and/or classes when it comes to this sort of thing. Also, you should not be storing passwords as plain text! That being said, see if this works for you (I know it works, so if you are having problems, you need to make sure your connection credentials are A-OK)!

You should have a better database connection like `PDO` or `MySQLi`. Make sure to fill out your db credentials in this `connect()` method.

**/classes/DatabaseConfig.php**

```
<?php
// This class will store your database connection
// and make it available everywhere because it is being
// saved to a singleton (single instance)
class   DatabaseConfig
    {
        private static  $singleton;

        public  function __construct()
            {
                if(empty(self::$singleton))
                    self::$singleton    =   $this;

                return self::$singleton;
            }

        public  function connect($host = "localhost", $username = "username", $password = "password", $database = "database")
            {
                // Create connection options
                $opts   =   array(  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $conn   =   new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password,$opts);

                return $conn;
            }
    }
```

Simple query function to return associative arrays:

**/functions/query.php**

```
<?php
// You can query your database with this function alone
// You can use a bind array in the second parameter to send
// variables for a safe query
function query($sql,$bind = false)
    {
        // This assigns the database connection class
        $db     =   new DatabaseConfig();
        // This is the PDO Connection
        $con    =   $db->connect();
        // This gives the option to straight query or bind
        if(!empty($bind)) {
                $query  =   $con->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute($bind);
            }
        else
            $query  =   $con->query($sql);
        // This will make an associative array 
        while($row  =   $query->fetch()){
                $result[]   =   $row;
            }
        // This will return the array OR 0 if no results
        return (!empty($result))? $result : 0; 
    }
```

Simple login script....albeit again, not a good idea to store plaintext passwords. You should be using the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions:

**checklogin.php**

```
<?php
// Create session start
session_start();
include_once(__DIR__.'/classes/DatabaseConfig.php');
include_once(__DIR__.'/functions/query.php');
// If the user has submitted the form 
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        // Use the query function to validate the username
        $username   =   query("select * from `users` where `username` = :username",array(":username"=>$_POST['username']));
        // IF there are returned hits
        if($username != 0) {
                // Check the password against the post
                if($username[0]['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
                        // If matches, then unset the not-so-secure password
                        unset($username[0]['password']);
                        // Assign the user row to session
                        $_SESSION['user']   =   $username[0];
                        // Redirect
                        header("location: SeniorDB_DBLibrary.php");
                        // Put exit here so the script stops processing
                        exit;
                    }
            }
    }
// Redirect
header("location: login.php?error=invalid");
// Put exit here so the script stops processing
exit;
```

**login.php**

```
<style>
div.fancy input {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.fancy {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
p,div.fancy {
    float: left;
}
div.fButton {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
div.fButton input   {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #444; 
}
.btnWrap    {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
form    {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
    <form action="checklogin.php" method="POST"> 
        <p>Username:</p>
        <div class="fancy">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"     required="required" />
        </div>
        <p>Password:</p>
        <div class="fancy">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap">
            <div class="fButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't really follow what's happening here. Are these all php files? Am i calling these files in the ones I already have or are these all replacing them? Should I enclose them as `<?php` and `?>` ?

Comment: Yeah, all php. Let me label better

Comment: Ok there you go. I have revised to indicate hierarchy. Hopefully it's a little clearer. Let me know if not, I may be able to further break it down on anything you don't understand

Comment: Make sure your database credentials are correct. That is the only way this won't work.

Comment: When I change everything to this, I still receive a blank / white screen. As someone asked me earlier, I use "localhost" as my server - when he says it should be the name of the server. But, I have pulled information USING `"localhost"` as my server inside the web pages so I'm not sure if that is the main issue. It is a school owned server and I am given and login / password, but the servername eludes me. --- Nevermind, the server is called localhost I believe. I'll add an image of the myPHPadmin

Comment: `localhost` will work under the certain circumstances, so that is hard to troubleshoot. put `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the `checklogin.php` page.

Comment: When using my own checklogin, I get this error `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/checklogin.php on line 4 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/checklogin.php on line 4 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/checklogin.php on line 5 (cont)`

Comment: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/checklogin.php on line 5`

Comment: And nothing shows up when putting that line in your code - just a white / blank screen

Comment: You have the wrong database credentials is what that that is saying. Also you did you fill in the database credentials in the `/classes/DatabaseConfig.php` under the `connect` method? Also if you put up that same error coding, there should be an error there too. It would redirect if there was no error.

Comment: Let me retry everything - `/functions/query.php` is that the name of the php file? I never named anything like that before - leading with a `/` because it usually doesn't let me

Comment: No, those are folders...you have to make folders and put the files into those folders.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you are using `localhost` based on your image but you just need to make sure you're username, password, and db are filled out properly.

Comment: I added the folders `classes` with the file `DatabaseConfig.php` and `functions` with the file `query.php` I changed everything (I believe) to match my credentials as a student. I did receive an error for your setup - `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/classes/DatabaseConfig.php:25 (cont.)`

Comment: `Stack trace: #0 /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/classes/DatabaseConfig.php(25): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password', Array) #1 /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/functions/query.php(12): DatabaseConfig->connect() #2 /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/checklogin.php(9): query('select * from `...', Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/sngamwon/public_html/SeniorProject/classes/DatabaseConfig.php on line 25`

Comment: You need to add your database credentials to this row of my class: `public  function connect($host = "localhost", $username = "username", $password = "password", $database = "database")`

Comment: This is the line in `DatabaseConfig.php` ---- `$conn   =   new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password,$opts);` Do I have to replace anything in that?

Comment: Omg I thought I had changed all that in the file before transferring it over. That literally did it. When it passed through to my main page, I literally stood up with my hands up like I was Rocky. That solved everything. I can see and understand how this all worked - thank you so much. Is there anything more I can do than give you a check / upvote?

Comment: Na it's all good. Best advise though, make sure you reuse those functions, that's what they are there to do. It'll save you tons of time in the long run

Answer (score -1):

ok, here's the answers to your questions directly:

1) You can not leave the server name as "localhost" you have to find the server name of the host that you're using.

2) Even if you don't get a server error, but still get a blank screen that means something has gone horribly wrong in your PHP code and it stopped the whole page from ever running in the first place. PHP gets read first, then processed. So if any errors in syntax or anything the likes, you'll just get a blank page.

3) The first login file you used was alright, but it wouldn't work because you had the HOST set as "localhost". Once you put that on a live website, it needs to change to the server name that you're on. Me on one computer, and you on another computer requesting "localhost" would not be what you want. at all. it wouldn't even work.

Comment: Well when I call the information or load user input information into the database, I use "localhost" and it works. Is doing a checklogin different than accessing the database to register username / passwords?